# Make Service Area is creating these feature datasets

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, feature-dataset, service-area

I'm running the Make Service Area tool in ArcPy and every time it creates a feature dataset in my gdb named "ServiceAreaSolver1xxxxxx." I've ignored them but they are taking up space and are annoying to scroll through. I now have several dozen in my gdb. I'm not sure what they're for.

Is my code missing something to delete this at the end of the process?

[image]

```
new = arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaAnalysisLayer('network','layer',
                                           travel_mode="Walking Time",
                                           travel_direction="Away from facilities",
                                           cutoffs=[5],
                                           output_type="POLYGONS",
                                           polygon_detail="HIGH",
                                           geometry_at_overlaps='DISSOLVE',
                                           polygon_trim_distance='100 Feet')



layer_object = new.getOutput(0)

sublayer_names = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(layer_object)

facilities_layer_name = sublayer_names["Facilities"]

arcpy.na.AddLocations(layer_object, facilities_layer_name, facilities, "","")

arcpy.na.Solve(layer_object)

polygons_sublayer = arcpy.na.GetNASublayer(layer_object, "SAPolygons")

arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(polygons_sublayer,outLocation,'layername')
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain the code you are asking about.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 0):

Network Analysis names all the datasets 'ServiceArea###'. You can run a cleanup with something like this:

```
dataSets = arcpy.ListDatasets("ServiceArea*", "All")
if dataSets:
    for ds in dataSets:
        # need to delete what is inside the dataset
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
            arcpy.management.Delete(fc)
        # before you can delete the dataset
        arcpy.management.Delete(ds)
```